# expand an existing fullchain certificate

Tags: letsencrypt, certbot

I want to expand an existing file instead of creating a new certificate for a subdomain.

I have these domains already in the file:

```
certtool -i < /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org-0002/fullchain.pem|grep DNSname
                        DNSname: forum.example.com
                        DNSname: m.example.de
                        DNSname: m.example.org
                        DNSname: example.com
                        DNSname: example.de
                        DNSname: example.org
                        DNSname: wiki.example.org
                        DNSname: www.example.com
                        DNSname: www.example.de
                        DNSname: www.example.org
```

(`certtool` is part of the package `gnutls-bin` in debian)

I know, there is the `certbot --expand` option, but if I don't get the exact set of domains again, it will create a new certificate with the next suffix `-0003`

How can I prevent that, if I only want to add one domain to an existing cert file?

Answer (score 0):

create a list out of the output with:

```
echo 'echo "-d $@"'>/tmp/runme.sh
chmod +x /tmp/runme.sh
domains_with_hyphen_d="$(certtool -i < /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org-0002/fullchain.pem|grep DNSname|cut -d ":" -f2| xargs -n 1 /tmp/runme.sh|xargs)"
certbot certonly --webroot -w /usr/share/nginx/html/ --expand -d newsubdomain.example.org $domains_with_hyphen_d
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for some certbot switch, so I don't have to write all the domains of an existing certificate, but such switch certbot doesn't have. So I came with this solution.

```
CERTNAME=example
DOMAINS=$(certbot certificates --cert-name ${CERTNAME}|grep Domains|cut -d\  -f 6-|sed 's/ /,/g')
NEWDOMAINS=new.example.com,othernew.example.com
certbot certonly --cert-name ${CERTNAME} --expand --domains ${DOMAINS},${NEWDOMAINS}
```

Note: If your certificate doesn't have --cert-name, use --domain instead, with any exiting DNS alt name of the existing certificate.